# Configurando o PHPUnit no Zend 2.5

Tags: php

Estou tentando configurar o PHPUnit no Zend, porém está dando um erro quando rodo o comando phpunit no terminal.

erro:

```
$ phpunit PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in /media/candidosouza/Development/GITHUB/Learning-ZF2/03-ZF2-Avancado/module/CJSN/tests/Bootstrap.php:75
```

Minha classe Bootstrap, foi tirado da documentação

[Classe Bootstrap Documentação](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#bootstrapping-your-tests)

[Minhas configurações estão no meu GitHub](https://github.com/candidosouza/Learning-ZF2/tree/master/03-ZF2-Avancado/module/CJSN/tests)

O erro está caindo nesse IF da classe Bootstrap:

```
if (!$zf2Path) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
        'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or'
        . ' define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.'
    );
}
```

Meus arquivos estão configurados como na documentação!
Alguém sabe me dizer o porque desse erro!

Como resolvo isso?

Obrigado!!!

Comment: rode o comando `composer install`, ou `composer.phar install`, para que seja montado todos os paths

Comment: Olá  André Henriques! Já está tudo instalado! Está mensagem de rodar o composer só acontece por causa do if na classe Bootstrap, mas todos meus componentes estão instalados

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção André!!!

Comment: Me desculpe por não responder, eu apenas olhei o erro e coloquei o comentario, pois reponder eu não posso, pois faz muito tempo que nao utilizo o zend.

Comment: O a dependencia phpUnit foi colocado no arquivo do composer?

Comment: Olá André, não está não, ele já vem instalado no Zend! Quando você instala as dependências pela primeira com o composer, já é instalado automaticamente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava no caminho path do arquivo [Bootstrap.php](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#bootstrapping-your-tests) 
na linha 69 e 70

```
elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library')) {
            $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library';
```

e na linha 85

```
include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
```

Estou usando a última versão do Zend, a 2.5, nessa versão o caminho path mudou, a estrutura de pastas foram alteradas.

Correção das linhas 69 e 70 são:

```
elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/zendframework/')) {
            $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/zendframework/';
        }
```

e a linha 85

```
include $zf2Path . '/zend-loader/src/AutoloaderFactory.php';
```

dessa forma o PHPUnit está rodando perfeitamente